# Getting error when using a function defined inside a php-file from another php-file

Tags: php, include-once

Say, I have a php-file named `functions.php` like below:

```
<?php

    include_once("db_connect.php");
    ### function to populate the City/State/Country drop-downs ###
    function get_option_list($table,$col_id,$col_value,$sel=0){
        $SQL = "SELECT * FROM $table";
        $rs = mysqli_query($db,$SQL) or die(mysqli_error());
        $option_list = "<option value='0'>Please select...</option>";
        while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs)){
            $option_list.= "<option value='$data[$col_id]'>$data[$col_value]
  </option>";
        }
        return $option_list;
    }

    //echo get_option_list("city","city_id","city_name");
    //echo get_option_list("state","state_id","state_name");
    //echo get_option_list("country","country_id","country_name");

?>
```

and another php-file named `db_connect.php` as below:

```
<?php
    $db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","sms1") or die(mysqli_connect_error());
?>
```

Now, I want to make use of the `get_option_list()` method from another php-file named `my_view.php` in the below manner:

```
<?php include_once("functions.php"); ?>
<form>
    <select>
    <?php echo get_option_list("city","city_id","city_name"); ?>
    </select>
</form>
```

Having all these files in place, whenever I'm running the `my_view.php` file, I'm getting errors like below:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: db in C:\xampp\htdocs\sms1\includes\functions.php on line 7
Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\sms1\includes\functions.php on line 7
Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\sms1\includes\functions.php on line 7
```

But, when calling the `get_option_list()` from the `functions.php` file itself, no such errors appear and I can see the expected output.
What I doubt is that there is some issue in my code which is not able to handle the value passing properly from one file to another. Can anyone please help me out here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method get_option_list has no parameter to pass the $db value.

You could include it:

```
function get_option_list($db, $table, $col_id, $col_value, $sel=0) {
```

And then pass it:

```
<?php echo get_option_list($db, "city","city_id","city_name"); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `$db` as global but it's not good practice.

```
 function get_option_list($table, $col_id, $col_value, $sel=0){
        global $db;
        $SQL = "SELECT * FROM $table";
        $rs = mysqli_query($db,$SQL) or die(mysqli_error());
        $option_list = "<option value='0'>Please select...</option>";
        while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs)){
            $option_list.= "<option value='$data[$col_id]'>$data[$col_value]
  </option>";
        }
        return $option_list;
    }
```

You can use PHP database library such as [Medoo](https://medoo.in/), [MeekroDB](https://meekro.com/) and so...

Or otherwise, you have to pass `$db` as a parameter.

```
get_option_list($db, $table, $col_id, $col_value, $sel=0)
```

Comment: Thanks @Manpreet for your feedback! Could you please let me know what is the good practice here in such scenario?